# ImportError: cannot import name Bunch scikit-learn 0.19

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am trying to creating a Pipeline using **sklearn.pipeline** using **Jupyter: Anaconda 4.3.24, python 2.7**.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
```

But I am getting the error related to **utils** directory as below:

ImportError: cannot import name Bunch:

[image: ImportError: cannot import name Bunch]

Moreover, when i comment the line

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

I again get error related to **utils** directory in the next line:

[image: ImportError: cannot import name euler_gamma]

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think euler_gamma package has not been installed in your system. Kindly read this [documentation](https://thinkingvirtually.blogspot.in/2017/08/anaconda-environment-setup-import-tensorflow-solved.html) on how to install packages using anconda prompt.

Comment: You should re-install sklearn.

Answer (score 5):

**upgrade** your scikit-learn

```
pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

Comment: have the same problem and this solution did not work

Comment: @AndreyVykhodtsev if you are using python3, use `pip install scikit-learn --upgrade` . Let me know if that helped